# Domino One (2005), does it exist?

Tags: domino-one

I was looking at IMDB's listing for [Domino One (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0446683/). It is very strange. No one seems to know much about it. Does anyone have any information about it? Why is it so hard to find information about it? Was it ever released?

The official website appeared to be www.dominoone.com (which is now down, but historically accessible via [The Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/)) but it contained no information other than the tagline "Welcome to the club." Several hours of googling turned up nothing. The mystery has sparked my interests.

Comment: I tried emailing both listed email addresses for the movie, `louvel@fas.harvard.edu` and `dominoone_themovie@yahoo.com`. As expected, both emails got `Recipient address rejected: User unknown` errors upon sending.

Comment: Did you try nickbenedict@yahoo.com? It is the admin email for Nick Garrison on the DominoOne.com website. Address is from 2005, so probably also defunct.

Comment: @MaryJoFinch good idea. I emailed `nickbenedict@yahoo.com` and surprisingly didn't get a mail error. Though I still think the chance is slim that I will get a reply.

Answer (score 6):

Domino One was a film made by Harvard students Nick Louvel and Nick Garrison using a camera lent by Ben Affleck. It starred Steve Guttenberg and Harvard students Tatyana Ali and Natalie Portman. It was entered into the 2005 DC Film Festival but did not win. It was never released to the public.

Helpful links:

[Random forum](http://www.pinoyexchange.com/forums/showthread.php?t=204752)

[Geocities site](http://www.geocities.com/~barneyoldfield/hcf070110.html)

[NataliePortman.com](http://www.natalieportman.com/npcom.asp?page_number=140)